# Can I clear all views in a ListView so they won't be recycled via convertView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I reuse the same `ListView` for navigating through data, while updating the `ListView` data based on the user clicking a row.  Up until now I had been using the same row `View` throughout the activity, but after the user clicks a row, I would like to change to a different row layout for *all* of the `ListView`'s rows.

To be more concrete, say the `ListView` contains rows using `layout1`, and the user clicks on a row.  The ListView's array adapter subsequently gets a new set of data and all the rows are now using `layout2`.

Rather than create a new `ListView` after the click or mess with `setTag` ugliness, I'd just like to clear all of the the cached row views that are sent via `getView`'s `convertView`.  I still want to subsequently recycle the `layout2` views.

Can I do this, or do I have to "bite the bullet?"

Comment: why not call invalidate for listview?

Comment: @tabbykitten I think that would just refresh the `ListView`, and likely still recycle the existing views.  I believe I did find [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11761180/403455) though.

Comment: A more optimized solution might be to build two adapters, and switch them, instead of switching the rowviews themselves.

Comment: @edthethird Would changing the adapter invalidate all of the existing row views though?

Comment: not directly no, you would have call invalidateViews() afterwards.  But it will be more manageable for you in the future if your first set of views are totally independent of your second set of views.  Instead of one super adapter, two normal adapters.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [ListView.invalidateViews()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews%28%29) will do this:

`public void invalidateViews ()`

> Causes all the views to be rebuilt and redrawn.

Comment: It did not to trick. Please see my answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049198/how-to-clear-the-views-which-are-held-in-the-listviews-recyclebin/16261588#16261588).