# How to clear the views which are held in the ListView's RecycleBin?

Tags: android, android-listview

In Android's `ListView` widget, the `ListView` will hold the views which is got from `getView` method of an Adapter in a inner class `RecycleBin`.

How can I clear the views in the `RecycleBin` and force the `ListView` to recreate all the child views.

Comment: If you are using convertView, try to don't use it. You should inflate a layout and then return it as a View instance.

Comment: The sole purpose of using a `ListView` is to reuse child views. Why would you want to go against the current?

Comment: I have got a method from you, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly a call to `invalidate` on a `ListView` widget will empty the cache of `Views` which are currently stored. I would advise against emptying the cache of views of a `ListView` because of the potential performance issues.

If you're not going to use the `convertView` item then you'll end up with having to build the row view each time(resulting in a lot of objects constructed each time the user scrolls) + the extra memory occupied by the recycled views from the `RecycleBin` which will never be used anyway.

Comment: Yes, I will use the convertView because of the potential oom issues. But in some exceptional case I need to change the type of listview's childview class, so I have to destroy all the views in recyclebin and call the getview method to recreate the childviews.

Comment: @zangtao In that case I think that a call to `invalidate` is what you need.

Comment: Calling **invalidate** or **invalidateViews** did not do the trick.

Answer (score 43):

Calling **[invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29)** or **[invalidateViews()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews%28%29)** did not do the trick for me (as mentioned in the correct answer). The recycled views were still stored in the **ListView**. I had to dig in Android source code to find a solution. I checked many methods, including the **[setAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29)** method of the **ListView** class (**Android API 15**) :

```java
@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {

    // ...
    mRecycler.clear();
    // ...

}
```

As you noticed, setting an adapter clears the recycler, which holds all the recycled views in a list view. You do not have to create a new adapter, setting the same adapter is enough to clear the recycled views list in the list view :

```
Adapter adapter = listview.getAdapter ();
// ... Modify adapter ... do anything else you need to do
// To clear the recycled views list :
listview.setAdapter ( adapter );
```

Comment: You're right setting the adapter does clear the recycler. As I said in my answer, I remember reading about `invalidate()` clearing the `ListView`(not 100% sure).

Comment: +1 That is indeed a neat trick, too bad that invalidate doesn't work here.

Comment: Nice one, thanks. I needed this on Android 5.0, where the ripple effect on a recycled view was still animating after clicking on an item, even though the items in the adapter were replaced and the list was refreshed.

Comment: The same thing applies to RecyclerView. Setting the same adapter will cause the Recycler to recreate all the views. I used this because the height of the views inside the Recycler changed.

Comment: Android seriously pisses me off sometimes, there is no reason we should be sitting here trying all these options and failing.

Answer (score 3):

There are a special method in `ListView` - `reclaimViews(List<View>)`. It moves all items that are currently in use and in recycle bin to specified list. Widget will request new views for items from `Adapter` before rendering next time.

You can use reclaimed views, if there are not many changes to item structure, or scrap them completely. For example, i'm using this method to dynamically update background drawable for items when selection color was changed by user.

Comment: Thanks this is the only correct answer here. I was adjusting row height in ListView when item is clicked in ListView. Noticed views were accumalated in ListView recycle bin resulting in OOM eventually. reclaimViews() were the trick to wipe recycle bin. Avoiding convert view would also work, but that affects negatively in performance.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion [@nekavally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27959188/3185295) offers the best solution. I have a `ListView` and a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Sometimes I need to change the size of the list items. But since the adapter recycles the views, they may appear in the wrong way. So I'm just calling `mListView.invalidateViews()` after reclaiming the recycled views, and it works just fine.

```
startAnimation(initialHeight, finalHeight, duration, new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        childView.getLayoutParams().height = 
                                (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        childView.requestLayout();

                        if (animation.getAnimatedFraction() == 1f) {
                            mListView.reclaimViews(new ArrayList<View>());
                            mListView.invalidateViews();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: reclaimViews() is the key. also you need to first invalidateViews() then reclaimViews() or else you'll lose the scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

Remove object of recycle bin from ArrayList or the data structure you have used in your custom adapter and also call `notifyDataSetChanged` method of your adapter.