# Clearing View cache of ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that I put through a complex bit of coding.  The list changes often with different types of data that require different views.  On rare occasion, I'll end up with 1 view being reused by Android for a row that's supposed to look different.  It seems to only happen when the data being displayed radically changes.  I was hoping there was a way to programmatically wipe the ListView's memory clean.  Is this possible?

Here is the beginning of my getView:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            SearchHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);

            if (null == convertView) {
                holder = new SearchHolder();
                if (type == SEARCH_TYPE_FREETEXT) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_search_item_freetext, null);
                    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_itemname);
                    holder.vHeaderWrapper = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_headerwrapper);
                    holder.txtHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_header);
                }
                else {
                    if (items.get(position).mData == null) {
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_loadmoreresults_white, null);
                    }
                    else {
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_search_item, null);
                        holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_itemname);
                        holder.vHeaderWrapper = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_headerwrapper);
                        holder.txtHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_header);
                    }
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (SearchHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
...
```

Comment: I've answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049198/how-to-clear-the-views-which-are-held-in-the-listviews-recyclebin which seems to be what you want.

Comment: I used `invalidate()`, but my problem still persists.  I'm putting new data into my ArrayAdapter and calling notify `notifyDataSetChanged()` and it is still reusing a layout that needs to be switched to another layout.

Comment: If you implement the `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType` methods correctly all should be ok(from your code it appears that you have only two types of rows so the complexity shouldn't be that big). I think you didn't update quite right the `getItemViewType` method to return the right thing when you update the data of the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

ListView does something called "recycling" when you scroll through a list, and what you will need to do is override the `getView()` method to update the individual listView item that is being recycled. By default android does not clear out these views. Check out the following link on ListView recycling:

http://mobile.cs.fsu.edu/the-nuance-of-android-listview-recycling-for-n00bs/

Without code it is hard to tell if you already know about this or not, but this is the cause of such problems in my experience.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing.  I've updated the OP to show this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use more than one layout for your list items then I suggest to inflate the appropriate layout from the xml every time in the getView() method.