# setadapter in expandablelistview different from setadapter in listview?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to clear listview after doing update with date (add or delete).
I have use setadapter like mention in here [How to clear the views which are held in the ListView's RecycleBin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16261588/3167956)

```
expList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
expListAdapter = new POIExpandableListAdapter(LocationSettingActivity.this);
expListAdapter = expList.getAdapter();

expList.setAdapter (expListAdapter);
```

But that useless, the view is add all data and updated data (not refresh), is there a different between setadapter in expandablelistview with setadapter in listview ?

Note : POIExpandableListAdapter is a class extends BaseExpandableListAdapter

Comment: Read em and weep [getAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#getAdapter()) [setAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setAdapter(android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how to refresh my list (clear previous data after update), in my case I need to recreate the vector again after update the data, not just the adapter :

```
        vector = new Vector<ArrayList<PointOfInterest>>();
        type = new Vector<String>();
        expList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expListAdapter = new POIExpandableListAdapter(LocationSettingActivity.this);
        expList.setAdapter (expListAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of `expListAdapter = expList.getAdapter();`

just after `expList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);`, `getAdapter()` is returning null overriding `expListAdapter = new POIExpandableListAdapter(LocationSettingActivity.this);`. The way you wrote it is equal to call `expList.setAdapter (null);`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `expListAdapter = expList.getAdapter();`

Your List haven't yet an adapter, so calling `getAdapter()` before `setAdapter()` will return a **null** object.

Change your code like that:

```
expList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
expListAdapter = new POIExpandableListAdapter(LocationSettingActivity.this);
expList.setAdapter (expListAdapter);
```

Comment: but, that code not refresh the list after I updated, it just add previously list and updated list ?

Comment: whats the difference between updating data and refreshing it?

Comment: for example, I have data : A, B; and I add data : C; the list should show A, B, C; after update, but my list is show : A, B, A, B, C; I think, that's the wrong way to update, buat I don't know how to clear previous list @rami

Comment: You need to clear your adapter dataSet before adding the new one (clear the parents List and childs  List). Show me how you load the new data.